# How to fix "object has no attribute" error when importing matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I'm recently trying to do something with Tensorflow. The installation seems very fine until I've encountered this problem. When importing matplotlib.pyplot, AttributeError was thrown. Below is the detail:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/syine/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2349, in <module>
    switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])
  File "/home/syine/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 820, in __getitem__
    plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
  File "/home/syine/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 212, in switch_backend
    newbackend[9:] if newbackend.startswith("module://")
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Seemingly it's an internal error in the module, however I can't find any hint to solve the issue.

I tried reinstalling matplotlib and all of its dependencies (FreeType, libpng, NumPy, setuptools, cycler, dateutil, kiwisolver, pyparsing), but none of them could solve the problem.

Comment: does `from matplotlib import rcParams, rcParamsDefault, get_backend, rcParamsOrig` work without errors? it seems that `newbackend` is no string, hence it has no 'startswith' method

Comment: @jww What I've uploaded is everything which causes the problem. Just importing a module throws an exception. Should I upload every pyplot code that I use?

Comment: what does `matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends` print you out? (you have to do `import matplotlib.rcsetup` first)

Comment: This is a strange error. Can you provide information about *how*  you run this code (which kind of interpreter, CLI etc.), your operating system and your matplotlib version (`import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__`). How exactly did you install matplotlib. Also what does `print(matplotlib.rcParams["backend"])` result in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14263

It sounds like it may be a problem with your environment and the fix in GitHub will only serve to raise a meaningful error message

Comment: Good point! I think the one guy updated `pillow`, `numpy` and `scipy`, then he was able to load the backends

Answer (score -2):

Use the function hasattr this will let you check whether a particular attribute belongs to a object or not before referencing it.